# Dialogs must be user-initiated issue and async. requests

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I get en ""Dialogs must be user-initiated" error.

Any clue how it could be resolved?

Thank you!

```
private void ExportDataToCSV()
        {
            string separator = GetSeparator();

            LoadClientContentItemStatistics(); // async. request of MVVM Light Toolkit

            foreach (var item in this._view)
            {
                sb.AppendLine("\"" + item.Player.PlayerGroup.Name + "\"" + separator + "\"" + item.Player.Name + "\"" + separator + "\"" + item.ClientContentItem.Name + "\"" + separator + "\"" + item.TotalTime.ToString() + "\"" + separator + "\"" + item.TotalQuantity.ToString() + "\"" + separator + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog()
            {
                DefaultExt = "csv",
                Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*",
                FilterIndex = 1
            };
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == true) // "Dialogs must be user-initiated" ERROR
            {
                using (Stream stream = sfd.OpenFile())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.Write(sb.ToString());   
                        writer.Close();
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                }
            }

            IsExport = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error means exactly what it says: the user must initiate this dialog. So, you can only call this method from a user click event or another user initiated event.

Comment: The typical solution is to pop up a message saying that you have data that needs saved and have a button for them to save/cancel

Comment: So have I show popup message, then get data async. and only after that show dialog window?

Comment: No, get data async, show a message, then showdialog off of that message's button click